# Microsoft VBA - Añadir elemento a un array

Tags: vba

Cómo puedo agregar un elemento a un array sea de Integer o String?

Intento lo siguiente:

```vb
Dim ArrayCadena() As String
Dim Celda As Range
Dim SS As Range

Set SS = Range("A1:A10")

For Each Celda In SS
    'Debug.Print Celda.Value
    ArrayCadena() = Celda.Value
Next Celda
```

Y la respuesta es:

> No coinciden los tipos - Error 13

Imprimo **Celda.Value** con **Debug.Print** y sí devuelve el valor correctamente, pero pues lo que quiero es agregarlo a un Array()

De qué forma puedo entonces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba estas soluciones:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub TEST_1()
Dim aTrg As Variant
    aTrg = Range("A1:A10").Value2
End Sub

Sub TEST_2()
Dim rTrg As Range
Dim aTrgInt() As Integer
Dim aTrgStr() As String
Dim b As Byte

    Set rTrg = Range("A1:A10")
    With rTrg
        ReDim Preserve aTrgInt(.Cells.Count)
        ReDim Preserve aTrgStr(.Cells.Count)
        For b = 1 To .Cells.Count
            aTrgInt(b) = rTrg.Cells(b).Value2
            aTrgStr(b) = CStr(rTrg.Cells(b).Value2)
    Next: End With
End Sub
```

Ve estas paginas para mayor información respecto a los recursos utilizados.

[Option keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278518(v=office.15).aspx), [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Using Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251519.aspx), [Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html)

Las paginas sugeridas están en inglés, sugiero usar un navegador con traducción.